# How can I sync PowerPoint timing with inserted audio files

Tags: audio, sync, microsoft-powerpoint

I try to put narration on a PowerPoint file. To have control on my voice, I recorded separate audio files for each slide. Then I inserted the audio files to each slide.

However, when I try to show it in slideshow or make a movie of it, the timing isn't sync with the end of each audio file. 
I would like automatic adjustment of slides' transition timing to end of the audio files, or in other words I would like to match the audio files with the slide show timings.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid your needs could not be achieved.

I find an article "[Record a slide show with narration and slide timings](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/record-a-slide-show-with-narration-and-slide-timings-0b9502c6-5f6c-40ae-b1e7-e47d8741161c)", at the end of the article, there are some recording tips, one of these is the following screenshot.

[image]

I also test on my PowerPoint 365, there is a delay when my narration is recorded. To ensure the integrity of narration, the slide show timings needs to be longer than the time the narration recorded.